# Merging info from two queries into a single table

Tags: mysql

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT num_requerimiento, asunto 
FROM masivos_texto INNER JOIN envios_masivos
ON id_masivos=id_envio;
```

**Result 1:**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|  num_requerimiento  |        asunto       |
|---------------------+----------------------
|      1800           |     inscripcion     |
|---------------------+---------------------+
|      1801           |     seguimiento     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT id_envio, estatus, count(estatus)
FROM acuses_recibo
WHERE id_envio IN (SELECT id_masivos FROM cati_atencion.masivos_texto WHERE fecha >= '2014-01-01' AND fecha <= '2015-06-16') 
GROUP BY id_envio, estatus;
```

**Result 2:**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|     id_envio        |        estatus      |    count(estatus)    |
|---------------------+--------------------------------------------+
|        84           |          0          |         4031         |
|---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|        84           |          1          |          632         |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|        85           |          0          |         35635        |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|        85           |          1          |         3711         |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+---------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------------------+ 
|  num_requerimiento  |     asunto      |  id_envio  |  estatus   |  count(estatus)   | 
|---------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------------------+ 
|      1800           |   inscripcion   |     84     |     0      |      4031         |
|---------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------------------+ 
|      1800           |   inscripcion   |     84     |     1      |       632         | 
+---------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------------------+ 
|      1801           |   seguimiento   |     85     |     0      |       635         | 
+---------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------------------+ 
|      1801           |   seguimiento   |     85     |     1      |       711         |
+---------------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-------------------+
```

in the **Desired Result** the id_envio/id_masivos corresponding to num_requerimiento 1800 is 84, 
and the id_envio/id_masivos corresponding to num_requerimiento 1801 is 85, 
and estatus in the 2nd table cant take up to three values, than i.a. for your assistance.

UNION doesn´t work, it gives me the 1st table followed by the 2nd, and only if the selects are of the same number of columns.

Comment: which sql variant mysql or mr. Softie

Comment: @DrewPierce MySQL...

Comment: Ok i will clean up tags bump to top

Answer (score 0):

To do this with SQL, you will need a table relating your `masivos_texto` and `acuses_recibo` tables.  I suggest you create a table. You could call it `req_id` or anything suitable. This is often called a JOIN table.  It will have this content

```
num_requerimiento    id_envio        
    1800               84
    1801               85
```

Then you'll be able to join your first and second queries together appropriately.

It's not possible to write your query for you without knowing the rows of your tables.

Comment: Certainly I have added a table `envios_masivos` that relates `num_requerimiento` and `id_envio`, with the structure `id | id_envio | num_requerimiento` `id` being autoincremental.

Comment: Table acuses_recibo: id, id_envio, id_mat_referencia, id_tipouser, estatus

Comment: Table masivos_texto: id_masivos, asunto, remite, mensaje, fecha, dirigido, adjunto, observaciones.   id_masivos in masivos_texto and id_envio in acuses_recibo are the same and 1 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! I needed to use aliases to each `SELECT`, as adding an alias to each select level, like this:

```
SELECT result1.num_requerimiento, result1.asunto, result1.id_masivos, result2.estatus, result2.conteo 
FROM 
(SELECT C.num_requerimiento, B.asunto, B.id_masivos 
FROM masivos_texto B INNER JOIN envios_masivos C
ON B.id_masivos=C.id_envio) as result1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT A.id_envio, A.estatus, count(estatus) as conteo 
from acuses_recibo A
WHERE A.id_envio IN (SELECT B.id_masivos FROM masivos_texto B where B.fecha >= '2014-01-01' AND B.fecha <= '2015-06-16')
GROUP BY A.id_envio, A.estatus) as result2
ON result1.id_masivos=result2.id_envio;
```

and that generates the 3rd table needed. Hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: Part of it was a language thing talking tables when they were result sets plus you never show schema so people were blind